# Spacemouse NDOF, panning view2d other than front, right and top

Tags: 3d-mouse

I’ve set up the 3Dconnexion spacemouse with NDOF configuration and in the 3D view it works to my liking.
Also when going in front, right, top orthographic view it works as expected and switches to pan and zoom.

What I am after now is being able to pan and zoom in the other 2D views like graph editor, dopesheet etc. I am unable to configure this.

I have tried to set de view2d pan action to NDOF, motion. But that resulted in a continuous pan when using the regular mouse.

Hopefully one of you can help me to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is what you are after, but I bound "shift" to my left button on the Spacemouse.

This allows easy panning in 2d views by keeping my hand on the Spacemouse.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Trey, thanks for your answer. I don't get it. The mouse isn't panning anything in the dope sheet for example. The image editor is panning just fine.

Comment: DJ, check out how mine is working.  https://youtu.be/LwN1bArpXU8  You can see smooth operation in 3d views, like you said.  It works in Dopesheet too, altho its more choppy.  My settings are at the beginning of the video.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll redo my settings. Maybe I messed it up at first setup when I didn’t know what I was doing.

Comment: all good now, turns out the 2dview.ndof setting was deleted while I was trying to set the mouse up. Thanks for your help.